# Azure DevOps test Plans

Tags: azure-devops, test-plan

How do I call multiple shared parameters in a single test plan? I can call a single shared parameter for now. It will be helpful if I can call multiple parameters in a single test plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write a manual test, you often want to specify that the test should be repeated several times with different test data. For example, if your users can add different quantities of a product to a shopping cart, then you want to check that a quantity of 200 works just as well as a quantity of 1.

To do this, you insert parameters in your test steps. Along with the test steps, you provide a table of parameter values. You can also share parameters and their data between test cases when you use the web portal with TFS 2015 and later or Azure DevOps. That way you can run multiple test cases with the same data.

Comment: Can i call multiple table of parameters for a single test plan?

Comment: You can't add more than one shared parameter set to a single test case.

Comment: If this answered your question please give reputation by clicked the up arrow or accepting the answer. it will be helpful!